# Can Markup documentation be added to Swift modules?

Tags: swift, xcode, markup

Xcode allows for Markup documentation of Swift/Obj-C to be displayed in the editor, e.g.:

```
/// A function
func foo() {}
```

results in
[image: documentation]

I've noticed that Apple's supplied frameworks have module-level documentation. E.g. Foundation:
[image: documentation]
Is there a way to add this module-level documentation to custom frameworks?

Comment: If I could find it the question I remember, I'd mark this a dup. But if I remember that question - the answer was no. Since I can't remember neither, I'm up voting because this deserves a straight answer.

Comment: Same question (without answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967185/how-to-document-a-ios-custom-framework-whose-description-can-be-revealed-at-xcod.

Comment: We definitively need a canonical answer for this question, even if it's a "no". But perhaps opening a radar on Apple would be a faster way to get an answer?

Comment: ~~Is it this?  http://www.openradar.me/29614691~~ EDIT: Oh, I see what you mean.  Never mind.

Comment: I've asked in Apple's developer forums; if I hear back from them first I'll post the answer here.

Comment: Odd, my Xcode 10.1 doesn't give me any quick help documentation for any imports, even Foundation and UIKit.